# Writing generic rule in Makefile

Tags: makefile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Makefile rule to build with same name, but different directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173813/makefile-rule-to-build-with-same-name-but-different-directory)

```
%.o: %.c
  $(CC) ...
```

defines a rule to compile all object files from their corresponding sources. But the issue with this is that the object file and the source file are expected to be in the same directory. How do I change this to do the following -

```
bin/%.o: src/%.c
  $(CC) ...
```

to put all generated binaries in a separate path and not mess up the path containing the source files.

Comment: If you're satisfied with the solution you found, you can post it as an answer to your own question (this is encouraged). You could also accept it after 48 hours, if no better answer has been posted by then. Accepting an answer signals that the problem has been solved. ;)

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173813/makefile-rule-to-build-with-same-name-but-different-directory

Comment: I mean you can post it as an actual Answer below. I'd do it, but I don't want to steal your rightfully earned reputation. :)